# Magento: Get all children of a specific category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Currently I have this to get children of a category:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childrenIds = $category->getResource()->getChildren($category, true);
```

However, it will get only active children. Is there a way to get all children of a specific category, including disabled categories?

Comment: Do you have the ability to write direct SQL against the DB?

Answer (score 0):

try the codes below

```
$categoryId = 8; // your parent category id    
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childrenIdsWithInactive = $category->getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive()->getAllIds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild){
        $allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId));
        foreach ($allCats as $category){
            $html .= $category->getId().",";
            $subcats = $category->getChildren();
            if($subcats != ''){
                $html .= getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
    $catlistHtml = getTreeCategories("category_id", false); ?>
```